# Stepper motor with HCSR-04 sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper

I want to make a stepper motor increase and decrease speed working with a HCSR04 sensor. The idea is that if the sensors detects an object the stepper motor is going to decrease, and stop as close as possile to the object.

I have made some code, and it is sorta working..

**My current code looks like this:**

```
if (distance > 30) 
{
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high   
  delayMicroseconds(500); // Wait   
  digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low   
  delayMicroseconds(500); // Wait 
}

if (distance > 20 && distance < 30)
{
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high   
  delayMicroseconds(2000); // Wait   
  digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low   
  delayMicroseconds(2000); // Wait
}

if (distance > 10 && distance < 20)
{
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high   
  delayMicroseconds(10000); // Wait   
  digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low   
  delayMicroseconds(10000); // Wait
}

if (distance > 1 && distance < 10)
{
  //digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high   
  //delayMicroseconds(1000); // Wait   
  digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low   
}
```

**But I thought it could be easier, So I made a function:**

```
void velocity()
{
 digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high
 delayMicroseconds(500); // Wait
 digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low
 delayMicroseconds(500); // Wait
}
```

Now my question is: Can I manipulate the delayMicroseconds to change if the distance changes? Is there a formula to do so?

**Entire code:**

```
int trigPin = 11; 
int echoPin = 10; 

void setup()
{  
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); //Sensor
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); //Sensor  
pinMode(6,OUTPUT); // Enable
pinMode(13,OUTPUT); // Step
pinMode(12,OUTPUT); // Dir
digitalWrite(6,LOW); // Set Enable low
digitalWrite(5,LOW); // Set Step low
Serial.begin(9600);
} 

void loop()
{  
//rotateleft();
//Serial.println("ik draai nu exact een rotatie linksom");
//delay(1000);
//rotateright();
//Serial.println("ik draai nu exact een rotatie rechtsom");
//delay(1000);
//velocity();

 //sensor
 long duration, distance;
 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(2);
 digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(5);
 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
 duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
 distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
 Serial.print ("cm ");
 Serial.print (distance);

//eigen creatie

if (distance > 30) 
{
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high   
  delayMicroseconds(500); // Wait   
  digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low   
  delayMicroseconds(500); // Wait 
}

if (distance > 20 && distance < 30)
{
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high   
  delayMicroseconds(2000); // Wait   
  digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low   
  delayMicroseconds(2000); // Wait
}

if (distance > 10 && distance < 20)
{
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high   
  delayMicroseconds(10000); // Wait   
  digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low   
  delayMicroseconds(10000); // Wait
}

if (distance > 1 && distance < 10)
{
  //digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high   
  //delayMicroseconds(1000); // Wait   
  digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low   
}

//Own functions
}

void velocity()
{
 digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high
 delayMicroseconds(500); // Wait
 digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low
 delayMicroseconds(500); // Wait
}

void rotateleft()
{
 digitalWrite(12,HIGH); // Set Dir high
 for(int x = 0; x < 200; x++) // Loop 200 times
  {
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high
    delayMicroseconds(1000); // Wait
    digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low
    delayMicroseconds(1000); // Wait
   }
  }
  void rotateright()
  {
   digitalWrite(12,LOW); // Set Dir high
   for(int x = 0; x < 200; x++) // Loop 200 times
   {     
     digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high
     delayMicroseconds(1000); // Wait
     digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low
     delayMicroseconds(1000); // Wait   
   } 
 }
```

Comment: You might look into using the `constrain()` function to establish a distance beyond which you will run at full speed, and then use the `map()` function to turn that into an *inverse* relationship between distance and delay.  Beware of possible hesitations while measuring, and the fact that ultrasonic sensors have a minimum distance, so make sure you don't go to full speed when something is closer than the minimum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a distance variable containing the distance measured from your sonar sensor in cm. You can use that value to adjust the delay times in between your steps.

**EDIT** Modified code to increase speed when distance increases

```
int time = 0;
int timeWait = 1000; //interval in milliseconds between each distance reading
int maxDelay = 1000;

void velocity(int speed){
   int trim = 10;
   digitalWrite(13,HIGH); // Output high
   delayMicroseconds(maxDelay - speed*trim); // Wait
   digitalWrite(13,LOW); // Output low
   delayMicroseconds(maxDelay - speed*trim); // Wait
}

int readDistance(){
 //code to read distance
 return distance;
}    

void setup(){
time = millis();
}

void loop(){
   if(millis()-time > timeWait){ //only read distance if 1000ms has elapsed since the last reading
     time = millis();
     int distance = readDistance(); //your distance reading code;

   }
   velocity(distance);
}`
```

**EDIT 2** 
You'll also need something to handle upper and lower limits for delays (i.e. you don't want delayMicroseconds(0) or any negative numbers and  you don't want to include extraneous distance readings)

Comment: This looks to increase the delay (ie, move slower) longer distance, which seems to be the opposite of the goal.

Comment: I'll edit to subtract from the maximum delay which should increase speed when distance increases.